# Capture address using google map

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I need can mechanism in `php` were user clicks on text box It will open an google map and when user selects the location, capture the address in text field.

[image: This is text box to capture address]

Thanks in Advance...!

Comment: `in php` can't be done in PHP, as PHP is a server side pre-processor that just sends web pages and stuff to browsers

Comment: Also, this isn't icanhazcode.com - where you can ask people to write code for you - read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @JaromandaX In `Js` will be fine for me

Comment: I'm sure it would

Comment: I don't want code to be written i just need an `hint` or `idea`

Answer (score 1):

You need the Google Maps JS API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) to display the map, and capture a click at a particular point.

When you capture the click, use AJAX to send to a server where you need the reversegeocoding api (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) to translate this into an address.

Follow those two links - there's a lot of reading you need to do to get access to the APIs set up, but there are loads of tutorials to take you through step-by-step.

Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

You can have js where you need to open the google map. And for a particular selection of the location you would get the latitude and longitude of the place.

Now here starts how to get these values in php. All you can do is, on selection you can call your custom function and pass `lat` and `lng` as parameter which will then make an ajax call to php script and send these values to server.

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't solve the question how to get the address from the location on the map. Passing the latitude and longitude to a PHP file just means that the server knows those numbers. Those numbers would have to be looked up in a large address database from the PHP or PHP would have to interact with an API.

Comment: Ok, There is an edit in the process. You can use reverse geocoding in javascript function rather than in php. And get the address from there and then pass this to the server.